# Angular material select don't show current ngx-translate language on the App start (before user pick a lang manually)

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, angular-material, ngx-translate

I'm using `ngx-translate` and it works fine. Following code (taken from official example) shows me current lang and allows me to switch it:

```
<select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
</select>
```

All `ngx-translate` infrastructure is taken from the doc and is going to be 
permanent. Then I want to use material select (`mat-select`) instead of native `select`:

```
<mat-select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
  <mat-option 
    *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" 
    [value]="lang" 
    [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang"
  >
    {{ lang }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

You see, nothing's really different. This code also would allow me to switch languages, but it won't show me current language before first change.

I created simple demo, its view is not perfect, but the issue can be reproduced easily: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-srb2dr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I wonder if I missed something, but I really stuck here trying to make material variant work and **show me current lang before I open dropdown and pick a lang**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. You have to set `[value]="translate.currentLang"` in `mat-select`. Also you don't need `selected` in `mat-option`.

```
<mat-select [value]="translate.currentLang" class="lang" #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
    <mat-option 
    *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" 
    [value]="lang"
    >
       {{ lang }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```